# WindowPhysicalFromPoint always return Unexpected value

Tags: c#

I use WindowFromPoint in wpf, but it alway return other Unexpected window handle.

My Code is

```
// My DPI is 1
 System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point();
 GetPhysicalCursorPos(out p);
 IntPtr hwnd = WindowFromPhysicalPoint(p.X, p.Y);
```

Sometimes it will return correctly when I mousemove on visual studio window and chrome window.

But I can't get notepad window handle when I active notepad window.
I'm afraid I misunderstood the meaning of the API.

Can someone explain it？

Comment: I try to use WindowFromPoint and WindowFromPhysicalPoint, but my dpi is 1, i think they are same